# Switching between Mobile view & Desktop view of Chrome browser in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a requirement where I want to test the system in mobile view and desktop view, so it requires my code to be able to switch between the views mid way, like first it tests TC1 in mobile view then it tests TC1 in desktop view then again TC2 in mobile view and TC2 in desktop view and so on.
When we initiate the browser it opens up in normal desktop view and I convert it to mobile view using the following code -

```
deviceMetrics.put("width", 414);
deviceMetrics.put("height", 1400);
deviceMetrics.put("pixelRatio", 3.0);
Map<String, Object> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<>();
mobileEmulation.put("deviceMetrics", deviceMetrics);
mobileEmulation.put("userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; en-us; Nexus 5 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19");
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
```

Is there a way I can convert the browser to Desktop view in the same session?

Comment: Can you try to clear those map `deviceMetrics.clear()` and `mobileEmulation.clear()` and do `driver.get("desktop view URL")`

Comment: this is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Since you need no to switch between the desktop and mobile modes during the same test case the simplest way to resolve your problem is to pass some parameter with the test. I guess you are using TestNG or jUnit? Just pass Boolean parameter `isMobileMode`
In this case you can simply

```
if(isMobileMode){
    chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
}
```

there while all the rest lines will be not changed.

Comment: I thought of the same way and I have done this in my other project but the current project has only one Test method and it requires to switch between mobile view & desktop view in single run
Using the above method I will have to use 2 different tests in TestNG.xml

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. Will you run this single test with TestNG with 2 different testng.xml files or not?

Answer (score 0):

Kind of situation I am also facing,
My application running fine in my local system, but when I am running it into Azure Devops (self hosted agent ) it is running in some different mode (may be tablet/ipad mini mode).
I tried with

```
Map devices = new HashMap()
{{put("width", 1366);
  put("height", 768);
  put("mobile", false);
  put("deviceScaleFactor", 100);
 }};driver.executeCdpCommand("Emulation.setDeviceMetricsOverride", devices );
```

But getting same response.